# php : iterate through foreach n-1 times where n value is unknown

Tags: php, foreach

I have multiple foreach loops :

```
foreach($result as $index1 => $value1)
{
   //count the length of array $value1. That is n value.

   //iterate through the loop n-1 times  
   foreach($value1 as $index2 => $value2)
   {
      //do something
      foreach(...) { }
   }
}
```

Here I want to run the 2nd foreach loop n-1 times. Is it possible to do so  ? or Is there any other way ? thank you for any help

Comment: what is n here ? is it the size of the first result subset ?

Comment: @DebasishPothal It says in the question `//count the length of array $value1. That is n value.`

Comment: Given we don't know what the values of the the keys are, one option is to simply have a counter variable in the first loop and increment / check the value and break when necessary out of the second loop.

Comment: I am taking the array values from a JSON response. keys are [0],[1],[2]...[n]. Here I want to print the values only till n-1.

Comment: foreach (array_slice($arr, 0, sizeof($arr)-1) as $k => $v) {
    /* code goes here*/
}

Comment: Try the above in the second loop, see if it works